# Remotely connect render.com mongodb service or an alternative way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, render.com

I need to setup mongodb on [render.com](https://render.com)  so I used their [Deploy to Render](https://render.com/docs/deploy-mongodb) button that did create a private service with mongo.

Now the problem is they allow private host:port value to connect internally and they also do have a shell on dashboard (under service) that lets to connect to mongodb via shell.

I am not good with docker, and I dont want to setup a (web) service using nodejs (that I hope would work internally) without being sure it is the right way. So if I have to use bind-ip or anything I need confidence/examples.

They have an open feature request [Ability to SSH into instances](https://feedback.render.com/features/p/ability-to-ssh-into-instances).

Any Ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear how the "allow private host:port value to connect internally" is a problem without context.

Comment: Well I want to connect remotly, maybe use mongoimport. Whats the use of having private host:port anyway if I dont want to setup a web service on render.com

Comment: Do I get it right that you create a private service on render and want to make it public? They don't provide such service. Try https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas it does what you need.

Comment: Thanks, Yes they don't (for now).
They officially support PostgreSQL https://render.com/docs/databases